# TypeScript type for whitespace-only string

Tags: typescript

I have an incorrect type guard like this:

```
const isNullOrUndefinedOrEmptyStringWhenTrimmed = (str: string | undefined | null): str is null | undefined | '' => {
  return str === undefined || str === null || str.trim().length === 0;
};
```

And then I want to use it (`null` and `undefined` cases are obvious, not showing them in the example):

```
const aString: string = "      ";

if (isNullOrUndefinedOrEmptyStringWhenTrimmed(aString)) {
    const val = aString; // Here I want it to be of type EmptyWhenTrimmed (but it is of type "")
} else {
    const val = aString; // Here I want it to be of type string (which it is here)
}

const aLiteral = "      ";

if (isNullOrUndefinedOrEmptyStringWhenTrimmed(aLiteral)) {
    const val = aLiteral; // Here I want it to be of type EmptyWhenTrimmed (but it is of type never)
} else {
    const val = aLiteral; // Here I want it to be of type "      " (which it is here)
}
```

So in the guard part `is null | undefined | ''` should be `is null | undefined | EmptyWhenTrimmed`, where `EmptyWhenTrimmed` is a type that fulfills the condition:

For each string `x`:  `x.trim(x) === ""`.

So how would I define `EmptyWhenTrimmed` type?

## Update

The thing that even led me to this, was that we have values coming from forms, and want to do stuff with those values. the `isNullOrEmpty()` and `isNotNullOrEmpty()` functions were already implemented by someone else. I just wanted to use the code.

Here the `Math.random()` is used to avoid TS inference.

```
const someFn = (str: string) => {
    // do something with str
}

const values: (string | undefined | null)[] = ["abc", "", null, undefined, "xyz"];

const val = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]

const isNullOrEmpty = (str: string | undefined | null) => {
    return str === undefined || str === null || str.trim().length === 0;
};

if (isNullOrEmpty(val)) {
    throw new Error('Value invalid');
}
someFn(val) // Argument of type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

const isNotNullOrEmpty = (str: string | undefined | null): str is string => {
    return !isNullOrEmpty(str);
}

if (!isNotNullOrEmpty(val)) {
    throw new Error('Value invalid');
}

someFn(val) // all good, val is string
```

The `isNullOrEmpty()` function is just a normal function, not a type guard. However in the first case, `someFn` complains about the value passed to it not being exactly string. I could use the already defined `isNotNullOrEmpty()`, but firstly it seemed clunky and unreadable to use `!isNotNullOrEmpty()` just to get the type narrowed, and secondly its name is quite weird as well, logically correct might be `isNotNullAndNotEmpty()`.

So I just thought screw it, I'm gonna make a type guard out of the first one. And quickly I realized that the fact that it's not straightforward is probably why `isNotNullOrEmpty()` was even created.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwDaoPICcCqYAmApgGZxiH7YCiAtgA5QCeAylFmQOYDqAFoWABV2NGhRgBeGAApoWAFwxZnGAB8YyAiTJi1YNKgCUC2fAgw96Ves2ly+KwHIHEgHwwA3gCgYMLISjIWGCKbBLikhpEtjpqJuGSFqiqsWwAdGxwNFIGqaj8HFA8YZIADADcngC+FZ6gkLAAhqzsYBzGGa0SMABEPn09NXDE0ggo6Nh4UdqUWLQMLB3cfILCovhSTYsGBh7efXXQMABuDUmSmy0cZTAA9DcwABKEfjAAkjAA7g1gsHCwUCAYAAjQgwEDDJh0UFzJi8fhCTJraRA5C-X5mcEwSGg7rdAxVGCEVAQUFefoHWAnM4wC6ca53R7PUHvL4-eD-QEgsEQxhQkKXaQfHhwYBFP6mGB8Pz4yqeWrgQ4NAAyf2epy6vX6AzlQxGSH0Exs02o9CYzU4cJWiIoGxVUDVhh2ZP2Csp6vOdod9PuTxeLO+aKxnNBmOxMBhjEtCJEYikKMDCG5WN5oPIR2eMsJxNJex8FOO7ppnqwp29jL9nwD7KDwJDPL5mv6vSkQpFYvRkqZMrlDPiff7A-EcvzEBAogAYsFJDI2O1LjtxG5nT4GfhAaPRIVlB8-kVZFVh66C6hkIQIAoZwK1JEtHYrIkDABtAC6XUf3QaQOA3QAND1f+Y+h-je0T4H+3QAB6MAAXt0z41PmVJdFSp4QI+ACyDSFKkxCoCAIBYFImHYSWBBjtkMAAFTHqhuT5IUBjPoe9SmGMmCzKajBdJec7KNeRp3ro+gLkuua+P4gTBHE4TWFMgkpFgxSAZYKgKekwjZHRrSFEp5RVIMwxSKMBocfMUhUtsuz9IUWAgB85iEPZVBYLZhEOAAaqcp7wGAVJwPgDgGBUsoboQk7macOwMgAglgHDIKIbKhimMAOEonRCSpsm3hQziJmAICNBAEBwBwYCfnkNZ0A0Jabs8SZhmliwOKkzGHKMhVsSa8zcbIvEZdloH3sJc4SulHCuFZfR+AEQQwAAhMZ4ymUwl5BQeni6lIi1IJ1JkRhFjpTT4Nl2Q5TkuQRUgeV5oJkH5AXrbKniheFFm3PcpxJBw+FgceY2LEAA) link for the examples above.

Comment: There is no such type in TypeScript.  You could jump through hoops with generic template literal types which could check a string literal type for "pure-whitespaceness", but that's not going to help with `aString`.  What is the use case here?  Given that the compiler would *only* know that `aString` is pure whitespace but not exactly what it is, ... is the goal that you would pass it to `trim()` and get `""` out?  If so, why not call `trim()` first and then test it for `""` instead of fighting with the type system?  I could imagine a nominal type that works this way, but it's yucky.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6x0em) is what you'd get with a nominal type, but I wonder if that's really your use case, or what?  How should we proceed here?

Comment: I updated the question with what even led me to this. In your example the type `PureWhiteSpace` is a superset of `string`. However I want it to be a subset, so whatever accepts `string` also accepts the `EmptyWhenTrimmed` type.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "subset" or "superset", but in my example `PureWhiteSpace` is indeed a *subtype* of `string` and whatever accepts `string` will also accept a `PureWhiteSpace`. If you think otherwise can you demonstrate it with a playground link?

Comment: A type like that is just not that useful at all. I still don't see why this type is necessary.

Comment: @jcalz You're right, it is in fact a subtype. And I just realized that this whole question is not even what I needed. All I actually needed is for the `isNullOrEmpty()` fn to narrow down the `string | undefined | null` to `string`, which actually happens if I just make the type guard like this: `isNullOrEmpty = (str: string | undefined | null): str is string | null | undefined`. Somehow I completely missed this as I was immediately trying to use `''` instead of `string`.

Comment: Actually what I said was wrong. cause now outside of the check it narrows it to `never`, which `someFn` accepts due to how `never` works. But this again is a lie because the value still is `string`.